# s3 bucket not allowing PutObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am saving a json file in s3 bucket, and I am using a lambda function created under IAM user cdeveloper.

The Policy on the Resource is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::355:user/cDeveloper"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ag-grid/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the test, I get:

```
START RequestId: abb632556 Version: $LATEST
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied: ClientError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in main
    run(event)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21, in run
    s3.Bucket('ag-grid').put_object(Key='assets/kpi.json', Body='kpi.json')
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

This is my function:

```
r = requests.get('http://endpoint/', headers=headers).json() 

#save to temp folder
with open('kpi.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(r, outfile)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket('ag-grid').put_object(Key='assets/kpi.json', Body='kpi.json')
```

I Have tried making Principal: * and it works, but its open to anyone.

Comment: Lambda functions typically gets permissions from an IAM role, not from an IAM user.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an IAM Role and associate the role with the Lambda function.

Then, either:

- Assign permissions to the role to access the S3 bucket, or
- Modify the Bucket Policy to refer to the Role's ARN, rather than a User ARN

It is better practice to assign the permissions to the Role, rather than having to modify bucket policies for every Lambda function and Bucket. (That is, delete the bucket policy, put the equivalent permissions in the Role.)